# MemoryError: stack overflow in python

Tags: python, stack, out-of-memory, overflow, heap-memory

This is the code for MIPS Single cycle data path processor. It is implementing IDEA algorithm (ASM code). I have numerous function calls and the whole architecture runs this assembly IDEA code for 16 times. I am getting this Stack overflow error. Previously i was getting a Recursion depth error but it got solved using the set.recusionlimit() function. The code seems okay but i dont know why it is giving me a Stack overflow error. Assembly code runs fine in a different assembler.

> MemoryError: stack overflow

```
#===========================================================
#SingleCycle Datapath Processor running IDEA algorithm asm
#Sukrut Kelkar
#===========================================================

import sys
import os

def main():

    global instrMem
    global dataMem
    global RegisterFile
    global WD3
    global Result
    global A3
    global RD3
    global PC
    global Branch
    global zero
    global Imm
    global RD
    global f
    sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
    f=0
    RD=0
    Imm=0
    zero=0
    Branch=0
    PC=-1
    Result=0
    WD3=0
    A3=0
    RD3=0

    #Instruction Memory
    instructM=open('instructionOpcodes_v1.txt','r')
    instrMem = dict(enumerate(line.strip() for line in instructM))
    print ('\ninstrMem: ',instrMem)

    #Register files
    RegisterFile = {k:0 for k in range(31)}

    #Data Memory
    dataM=open('keys.txt','r')
    dataMem = dict(enumerate(line.strip() for line in dataM))
    print ('\ndataMem: ',dataMem)

    ProgramCounter()

def ProgramCounter():
    global PC
    PC=mux((Branch & zero),adderPC(PC),Imm)
    A=PC
    instrMemo(A)

#Instrction Memory Module    
def instrMemo(A):
    global Op
    global funct
    global RD
    global A1
    global A2
    global Ard
    global Imm
    global instr

    for i in instrMem:
            if A==i:
                RD=instrMem[i]

    #scale_data= 16 ## equals to hexadecimal
    instr=bin(int(RD, 16))[2:].zfill(32)

    if int(instr,2)==1:
        sys.exit("Its Done!!!")

    Op=int(instr[0:6],2)#opcode
    funct=int(instr[21:27],2)#funct
    rt=instr[11:16]#A2 rt
    rd=instr[16:21]# rd
    rs=instr[6:11]#A1 rs
    Imm=int(instr[16:32],2)#Immediate offset
    #Imm=int(Im,2)
    A1=int(rs,2)
    A2=int(rt,2)
    Ard=int(rd,2)
    ControlU(Op,funct)


#Control Unit Module    
def ControlU(Op,funct):
    global RegWrite
    global RegDst
    global AluSrc
    global Branch
    global MemWrite
    global MemtoReg
    global AluCon
    global ALUresult
    global A3
    #R-type Instructions
    if Op==0:
        RegWrite=1
        RegDst=1
        AluSrc=0
        Branch=0
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=0

        if funct==0:
            AluCon=0
        elif funct==1:
            AluCon=1
        elif funct==2:
            AluCon=2
        elif funct==3:
            AluCon=3
        elif funct==4:
            AluCon=4
        elif funct==5:
            AluCon=5
    #Load Word       
    elif Op==2:
        RegWrite=1
        RegDst=0
        AluSrc=1
        Branch=0
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=1
        AluCon=0
    #Load Imm
    elif Op==1:
        RegWrite=1
        RegDst=0
        AluSrc=1
        Branch=0
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=0
        AluCon=0    
    #Store Word      
    elif Op==3:
        RegWrite=0
        RegDst=0
        AluSrc=1
        Branch=0
        MemWrite=1
        MemtoReg=0
        AluCon=0    
    #Branch if equal
    elif Op==5:
        RegWrite=0
        RegDst=0
        AluSrc=0
        Branch=1
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=0
        AluCon=1
    #Add Imm
    elif Op==9:
        RegWrite=1
        RegDst=0
        AluSrc=1
        Branch=0
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=0
        AluCon=0
    #Branch if zero
    elif Op==4:
        RegWrite=0
        RegDst=0
        AluSrc=0
        Branch=1
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=0
        AluCon=12
    #Branch if greater than
    elif Op==6:
        RegWrite=0
        RegDst=0
        AluSrc=0
        Branch=1
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=0
        AluCon=6    
    #Branch if less than
    elif Op==7:
        RegWrite=0
        RegDst=0
        AluSrc=0
        Branch=1
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=0
        AluCon=7
    #AddMod
    elif Op==11:
        RegWrite=1
        RegDst=1
        AluSrc=0
        Branch=0
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=0
        AluCon=11  
    #MulMod
    elif Op==10:
        RegWrite=1
        RegDst=1
        AluSrc=0
        Branch=0
        MemWrite=0
        MemtoReg=0
        AluCon=10
    A3=mux(RegDst,A2,Ard)
    print ('A3: ',A3)
    RegisterFiles(A1,A2)

#Register File Module
def RegisterFiles(A1,A2):
    global RD1
    global RD2
    global SrcA
    global SrcB
    for i in RegisterFile:
        if (A1==i):
            RD1=RegisterFile[i]

    for i in RegisterFile:
        if (A2==i):
            RD2=RegisterFile[i]

    SrcB=mux(AluSrc,RD2,Imm)
    SrcA=RD1
    ALU_main(AluCon,SrcA,SrcB)


#Arithmetic Logic Unit ALU 
def ALU_main(AluCon,inp1,inp2):
    global ALUresult
    global zero

    if AluCon==0:#add
        ALUresult=inp1+inp2

    elif AluCon==1:#sub
        ALUresult=inp1-inp2

    elif AluCon==2:#mul
        ALUresult=inp1*inp2

    elif AluCon==3:#or
        ALUresult=inp1 | inp2

    elif AluCon==4:#and
        ALUresult=inp1 & inp2

    elif AluCon==5:#XOR
        ALUresult=inp1 ^ inp2

    elif AluCon==11:#AddMod
        ALUresult=inp1+inp2
        while ALUresult>65536:
            ALUresult=ALUresult-65536         

    elif AluCon==10:#MulMod
        if inp1==0:
            inp1=65536

        if inp2==0:
            inp2=65536

        #ALUresult=int(inp1,2)*int(inp2,2)
        ALUresult=inp1*inp2
        if ALUresult==65536:
            ALUresult=0

        while ALUresult>65537:
            ALUresult=ALUresult-65537

    elif AluCon==6:#BGT
        if inp2>inp1:
            ALUresult=0
        else:
            ALUresult=1

    elif AluCon==7:#BLT
        if inp2<inp1:
            ALUresult=0
        else:
            ALUresult=1

    elif AluCon==12:#BZ
        if inp1==inp2:
            ALUresult=0
        else:
            ALUresult=1

    if ALUresult==0:
        zero=1
    else:
        zero=0
    dataMemo()

#Write      
def RegisterFileWrite():    
    global WD3
    Result=mux(MemtoReg,ALUresult,RD3)
    WD3=Result
    if RegWrite==1:
        for i in RegisterFile:
            if (A3==i):
                RegisterFile[i]=WD3

    final()


def dataMemo():
    global RD3
    global Result
    WD=RD2
    A4=ALUresult

    if MemWrite==0:
        for i in dataMem:
            if A4==i:
                RD3=int(dataMem[i],16)
    else:
        for i in dataMem:
            if A4==i:
                dataMem[i]=hex(WD)[2:]
        os.system('cls')

    RegisterFileWrite()


def mux(sel,firstinp,secondinp):
    if sel==0:
        out=firstinp
    else:
        out=secondinp
    return(out)


def adderPC(inp):
    addOut=inp+1
    return(addOut)  

def final():
    global f
    f+=1
    print (f)
    print ('\nPC: ',PC)
    #if RegisterFile[24]>4:
    print ('dataMem: ',dataMem)
        #j=112
        #while j<175:
    if RegisterFile[24]==4:
        print ('Instruction: ',instr)
        print ('Op: ',Op)
        print ('Funct: ',funct)
        print ('Imm: ',Imm)
        print ('SrcA: ',SrcA)
        print ('SrcB: ',SrcB)
        print ('ALUresult: ',ALUresult)
        print ('zero: ',zero)
        print ('RegisterFile: ',RegisterFile)
        print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
        #sys.exit("count is 4")
         #   final=dataMem[j]+dataMem[j+1]
          #  j=j+1
        #print ('\nEncrypted Data: ',final)

    ProgramCounter()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the stackoverflow because you set the recursion limit too high. [You can't set it as high as you like](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)

> `sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)` Set the maximum depth of the Python
>   interpreter stack to limit. This limit prevents infinite recursion
>   from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python.
>
> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent. A user may need to
>   set the limit higher when they have a program that requires deep
>   recursion and a platform that supports a higher limit. This should be
>   done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash.
>
> If the new limit is too low at the current recursion depth, a
>   RecursionError exception is raised.
>
> Changed in version 3.5.1: A RecursionError exception is now raised if
>   the new limit is too low at the current recursion depth.

Your real problem was that you are hitting the recursion limit. Why didn't you just post that traceback?

You appear to be using function calls like goto. Python doesn't do tail call optimisation so this technique won't work.

Comment: I am not using any calls like goto. But ya i am calling one function from another function. Here is the link for the traceback https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5iWxblKyV7_LTNZUGFBTFJzVU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Solved. Function call into another function was the error it seems. Thanks a lot for the help.